# Is it possible to ignore a specific file or directory in ls or file globbing?

Tags: grep, ls, wildcards

I am having trouble using the ls command, file globbing, and the grep command.   Consider the following file/directory tree.

```
abc/
    def
    ghi.txt
    jkl

def/
    f01
    abc
    abc.txt

ghi.txt
```

Suppose If I want to completely ignore the abc/ directory and report everything else.  Trying `ls -lR -Iabc .` does report the /def/abc.txt file but ignores the `/def/abc` file.  Similarly `ls -lR . | grep -v abc` is also no good here.  Is there any way to do what I want in bash?

Alternatively, suppose that I want to ignore `ghi.txt` but report `abc/ghi.txt`.  Is there any way to do this in bash?

Comment: I saw something like this before, and all you had to do was add `/` at the end of the pattern. Does that work here? (ie. `ls -1R -Iabc/ .`)

Comment: @iggy12345 no it doesn't, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, if extended globbing is enabled, then you could use !(abc) to inverse-match the `abc` directory. Ex. given

```
$ tree
.
├── abc
│   ├── def
│   ├── ghi.txt
│   └── jkl
├── def
│   ├── abc
│   ├── abc.txt
│   └── f01
└── ghi.txt

2 directories, 7 files
```

and

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
```

then

```
$ ls !(abc)
ghi.txt

def:
abc  abc.txt  f01
```